# Updating the structure of the published pages on existing site

Tags: c#, episerver

I have an existing Episerver-based website and it doesn't update the structure of the published pages when it is changed.

I have a huge amount of published pages derived from **BasePage**. Then I have to add a new block to that page:

```
public abstract class BasePage : PageData
{
    [Display(Name = "SomeBlock")]
    public virtual SomeBlock SomeBlock { get; set; }
}
public class SomeBlock : BlockData
{
    [CultureSpecific]
    [Display(Name = "Field1")]
    public virtual string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to update the page in Scheduled Job. The code would look like

```
BasePage writeablePage = (BasePage)basePage .CreateWritableClone();

 if (basePage.SomeBlock == null)
     basePage.SomeBlock = new SomeBlock ();

 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(basePage.SomeBlock.Field1))
 {
     basePage.SomeBlock.Field1 = "Some Text";
 }


 DataFactory.Instance.Save(writeablePage, SaveAction.Publish, AccessLevel.NoAccess);
```

But this approach doesn't work. I have tried to play with "SaveAction" but with no effect

Update: I am using the DB from the staging environment and it looks like the problem with versioning (Let's say I have 1.* assembly locally but there is 2.* on the staging server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the lower version of local Assembly then on the staging server which DB was used.

The local solution:

1. Get the DB version (it is possible to check in Admin mode)
2. Set the Assembly info version higher then in DB